# Mercurial GUI client for OS X with cherry-picking?

Tags: macos, user-interface, mercurial, cherry-pick

This is the one feature that I'm missing from GitX. Is there any such client out there?

What I mean by cherry-picking is the ability to include only certain rows in a commit. Like crecord, but with a nice GUI.

Answer (score 1):

As TortoiseHg is available for Linux, I expect it to run on Mac OS X, too. Cherry-picking can be done with the extension "transplant".

Comment: transplant does cherry picking of changesets from one branch to another, but the request is for line-by-line not changeset by changeset.  TortoiseHg can do that to, but it does it with a 'stash' like feature.

Answer (score 0):

[Atlassian's SourceTree](http://www.atlassian.com/software/sourcetree) seems to have cherry-picking as well. Haven't had the time to try it out yet though.